# Cannot run PlayFramwork 2.1 IntegrationSpec with Twitter Bootstrap js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I have a PlayFramework (2.1) project with bootstrap.js included in the main.scala.html file, whenever I run the 'test' command from the console, the whole process hangs. Its strange because I have no problem when using the 'run' command.

This is really easy to reproduce:

- create  a new PlayFramework 2.1 scala project.
- add bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js to the public/javascripts folder
- add a script tag in main.scala.html directly after the existing jquery include
- enter the play console
- run the 'test' command

The ApplicationSpec will run if it happens to get called first but the IntegrationSpec will never run and the console waits until killed.

I'm using PlayFramework 2.1, Bootstrap 2.3.1, Java 1.6.0_43 and Scala 2.10.0. I get the same problem on Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7.

I haven't changed the ApplicationSpec or IntegrationSpec files from what gets generated by 'play new'. The only thing I've changed is adding the bootstrap.js file to the javascripts directory and adding the script entry to the main.scala.html. Eveything else is a newly created, standard, play 2 scala application.

Can anyone else verify if this is an issue (or just me) and what the problem might be?

Comment: The problem might be in your ApplicationSpec or IntegrationSpec because you can execute 'run' command without any problem. Can I see your test code and directory structure?

Comment: I haven't changed the ApplicationSpec or IntegrationSpec files from what get generated by 'play new'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same trouble when I used bootstrap2.3.1 and jquery-1.9.1( not jquery-1.9.0 ). It happened because twitter bootstrap.js of version 2.3.1 is broken. I tried to use jquery-1.7.1 and bootstrap-2.0.4 and test with IntegrationSpec, then it works without any trouble. 
So you should try some patterns of jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: I was able to work around the problem by using an older bootstrap version. Thanks.